# Can't get Wordpress custom post type attachments to function in indexed array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, attachment, custom-post-type

Searched for many hours without success. My question is simple, but the answer seems elusive. I want to display the first three attachment images separately in each post of a custom post type. The following code has got me part way there, but I'm not sure how to proceed?

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
    ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium');
} ?>
```

Ok, added the attachments dump here:

```
Array
(
[106] => WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 106
    [post_author] => 2
    [post_date] => 2013-03-13 13:38:11
    [post_date_gmt] => 2013-03-13 12:38:11
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => autumn_leaves_new2
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => inherit
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => open
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => autumn_leaves_new2
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2015-08-15 06:01:05
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-08-15 06:01:05
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 278
    [guid] => http://localhost/pbvcid/wp
content/uploads/2013/03/autumn_leaves_new2.jpg
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => attachment
    [post_mime_type] => image/jpeg
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
    )
```

I think I need to be a bit clearer in my explanation. The code I supplied is just a start to be expanded upon as my php knowledge is limited. I believe what I am looking for is a way to put the custom post type attachments into an indexed array so that I can then chose a few individual attachments from that array and display them in their own individual div. So far the code is not functioning efficiently and does not display all the attachments in the posts, (thanks for all the help so far btw).

Comment: just edited my answer based on the array you've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that displays the array correctly:

```
$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
    ) );

    $imgArray = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

    $imgArray[$counter] = $attachment_id;
    $counter++;
    if($counter > 2) {
    break;
    }
    } 
    ?>
<div class="attachment1"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imgArray[0], 'medium'); ?></div>
<div class="attachment2"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imgArray[1], 'medium'); ?></div>
<div class="attachment3"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imgArray[2], 'medium'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code for getting the attachments.

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => 3,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
    ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium');
} ?>
```

Comment: @Paubab for more you can visit [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)

Comment: It's usually best to include a description with your code changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
 ));
foreach ( $attachments as $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'medium' );
}
```

if that doesn't work dump your attachments variable and post the results back here,

you can dump it like this

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($attachments, 1), '</pre>';
```